# Getting a label to appear first in Kivy?

Tags: python, label, kivy

I'm using Kivy with Python 2.7.  I have a simple program that discovers Bluetooth devices.  I want to display a label that shows "Scanning for Bluetooth devices" before it actually scans.  However, even if the code for the label is placed above the scanning procedure, the screen remains blank until the devices have been scanned when running.

```
class Boxes(FloatLayout, AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global name 
        global devList 

        super(Boxes, self).__init__(**kwargs) 

        layout = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='right', anchor_y='top') 
        layout.add_widget(Label(text='[color=1f358e][font=tahoma]Scanningfor Bluetooth devices...[/color][/font]', markup = True, font_size='20sp', pos=(0,250)))
        self.add_widget(layout)

        devList = discover_devices() 

        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')


        for device in devList: 
            name = str(lookup_name(device))
            if str(lookup_name(device)) == "":  
                name = "Unknown device" 
            deviceinfo = "[color=1f358e][font=tahoma]Device name: [color=1f358e][font=tahoma]" + str(name) + "\n[color=1f358e][font=tahoma]MAC address: [color=1f358e][font=tahoma]" + str(device) 
            box.add_widget(Button(text=deviceinfo, markup = True, font_size='17sp'))

        self.boxes.add_widget(box)
```

Comment: presumably `discover_devices` is blocking. Rather, run discovery in a separate thread or process, and once results are available, update your widgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't try it myself because I can't get the bluetooth module to work, but i believe this should work.

```
from threading import Thread

class Boxes(FloatLayout, AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global name
        global devList

        super(Boxes, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        layout = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='right', anchor_y='top')
        layout.add_widget(Label(text='[color=1f358e][font=tahoma]Scanning for Bluetooth devices...[/color][/font]', markup = True, font_size='20sp', pos=(0,250)))
        self.add_widget(layout)

        # Add the self. in front so we can access it from inside other functions
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        discoverThread = Thread(target=self.discover)
        discoverThread.start()


    def discover(self, *args)
        devList = discover_devices() 
        for device in devList: 
            name = str(lookup_name(device))
            if str(lookup_name(device)) == "":  
                name = "Unknown device" 
            deviceinfo = "[color=1f358e][font=tahoma]Device name: [color=1f358e][font=tahoma]" + str(name) + "\n[color=1f358e][font=tahoma]MAC address: [color=1f358e][font=tahoma]" + str(device) 
            self.box.add_widget(Button(text=deviceinfo, markup = True, font_size='17sp'))

        # Not sure what the .boxes is, but I suppose you know?
        self.boxes.add_widget(box)
```

Comment: Dude, you are awesome.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Would be cool if you accepted the answer. Cant really help others that well without reputation :p (Including you with your other posts)

Comment: Oh whoops, I wasn't even aware that I should do that, mb.